# Servlet called from Icefaces webapp creates constantly high CPU usage on client

Tags: java, performance, jsf, servlets, icefaces

I'm developing a web application (using JBoss and Icefaces) which uses a Servlet to create a Excel or PDF file and sends it to the browser.

But I'm experiencing performance problems after the servlet was called, resulting in a constantly high (~50%) CPU consumption of the browser. Testet in Firefox and Internet Explorer on different machines. The high cpu usage arises with a little delay (half a minute) after the servlet was called and stays high (until I close the browser or reload the page).
Whether I download the created file or open it directly makes no difference.

I'm clueless how this can happen...

Is there a way to analyze/debug the browser to find out, what is causing the cpu consumption?

**UPDATE:**

I've found out that is definitly related to the Icefaces webapp. When I replace my direct html-link to my servlet with a javascript call which opens the servlet in a new window (with window.open), then I can download the created file without problems.

Also when I logout inside my application, the CPU usage goes back to normal again!

**UPDATE:**

Ok, now Firebug helped me on: After the servlet was called I can see in the Firebug Console that there are XMLHtppRequests every milliseconds. Now I can understand the CPU usage!

```
POST http://localhost/webapp/block/receive-updated-views
```

is coming on and on. Have to check this...

**UPDATE:**
Ok I found an [iceface thread](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/13613.page) (with the corresponding iceface jira bug) but the bugtracker states this should be fixed already... somehow not for my case!

Comment: Does the problem depend only on the Excel or PDF document? That is, if you serve it from another server without Java or Servlets? If so, this question doesn't need the [java] and [servlets] tags.

Comment: Thx. It is definitly related to the webapplication which uses servlets and icefaces. I don't have any other problems with Excel downloads or my browser.

Answer (score 1):

Browsers doesn't run servlets. Browsers runs/displays the output which is produced by the servlet. It's the output which is causing a high load. Based on the as far given little information, it's hard to tell what's the problem with the output. [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com) can give lot of insights of what's going on in the webbrowser.

Usually, an extraordinary large HTML table or an inefficent piece of JavaScript code can consume a lot of CPU/memory resources. But with a binary file download like XLS/PDF, this should in fact not happen. The cause is then probably deeper. Do you see lot a resource usage when you do a file-to-file copy on the harddisk? If so, then it may probably be a bad harddisk or bad harddisk driver or harddisk DMA is being turned off.

---

**Update**: as per your investigation with help of Firebug, it look like that you're using IceFaces' `ice:commandButton` or `ice:commandLink` to download the file. Replace them by the normal JSF `h:commandButton` or `h:commandLink` so that it doesn't unnecessarily generate JS code which is responsible for that.

Comment: Thx. As it is a binary file I indeed don't understand why it is happening. And as it occurs on different machines it is related to the web application and definitly not the harddisk.

Comment: Thx again. Actually I'm not using a commandButton but a plain html a href

Comment: OK, this is then IceFaces' own oddity. Since I don't use IceFaces, I can't give a more detailed answer. At least my Firebug suggestion has helped you to nail down the root cause :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried FindBugs or other tools for static code analysis?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tools_for_static_code_analysis#Java

Answer (score 1):

If the CPU consumption is really coming from the browser, then you can't do anything about it - it is either the PDF or excel viewer .

If the server is on the same machine, and the cpu load comes from the servlet, then you have to optimize it. Give us code for that.

Comment: Thx. CPU Consumption occurs in the browser - not on the server! And as it occurs also when I download the file it cannot be an browser addon or viewer I suppose!

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved (actually it's more a workaround).

It's a Iceface Prob, which should be fixed according to the [bugtracker](http://jira.icefaces.org/browse/ICE-4648?page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Aall-tabpanel).
But as it is actually still present I could only fix it by calling the servlet in a new windows, created by javascript. (As already mentioned in my edited question).
It's really not a nice solution and has the drawback, that browser must not block popups.
But it's also a solution I've seen several times in the net (like [here](http://www.icefaces.org/JForum/posts/list/5446.page)).

```
public void exportToExcel(ActionEvent e) {
   JavascriptContext.addJavascriptCall(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance(),  "window.open (\"downloadServlet.dl?contentType=excel\",\"report\")");
}
```